# Call method before each method

Tags: java, methods, call

Is it possible to call a method before every method without calling it programmatically before every method?

For example when I've got a logger which should log "Hey" before each method, I could log manually before every method. But is there a way that every method triggers the log?

Comment: what are you trying to say dude?

Comment: google `aop` or `aspect oriented programing`

Comment: research on Spring AOP

Comment: @user748316: why does it have to be Spring?

Answer (score 5):

You are looking towards Aspect Oriented Programming. Since you are using Java, you can use AspectJ (https://eclipse.org/aspectj/) for this. In here you can use aspects to be called before the particular method.

Comment if you need more info on implementation.

Answer (score 1):

There are many thing you can do,

Use  preProcessor method, Interceptors , Handlers, Aspect Oriented Programming etc.